# How can resolve this (AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'PhotoImage')

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry for my long note

I am working on a program in python 3 with Tkinter, the program content only Admin side, the admin will Register a Student with his Name, Phone number and upload his image via upload image button in the program, When the Registration is done, the admin will search a Student and if exist, his details will be displayed and when you double click on the Student's name his image will appear. The problem is when I double click to display the image I keep getting this error message,

AttributeErrow: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'PhotoImage'

**Some portion of the code**

```py
photoPath = "Temp Images\\" + pc[1] + ".jpg"
writeTofile(pc[5], photoPath)
self.photo = Image.PhotoImage(Image.open("Temp Images//" + pc[1] + ".jpg"))
Label (image=self.photo, width=150, height=150).place(x=625, y=20)
filelist = glob.glob("Temp Images\*.jpg")
for file in filelist:
    is.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
ImageTk.PhotoImage
```

Example:

```
python3.9
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 19 2021, 11:32:47) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import ImageTk
>>> print(ImageTk.PhotoImage)
<class 'PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage'>
```

Comment: It has has worked, but it raised an error message again in 54.

Comment: Hey can I follow you on Telegram and Facebook?, Help me with the link please

Comment: What is 54? Please, clarify.

Comment: Ok Sir, let me make it clear